# How would one reference document in a chrome background js script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to make an extension with chrome, but it seems like when I try to run this simple code:

```js
function reddenPage() {
  var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('nav rbx-navbar hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4');
  //console.log(bar[0].appendChild(bar[0].childNodes[2].cloneNode(true)));
  if(bar[0]==null){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

It returns : [image: Error]

*Any help would be lovely, thank you so much!*

Comment: show me **minfest.json**

Comment: That should be an error of  `DOM` not ready.

Comment: Are you trying access content document?

Comment: @cfarhad Sorry, I don't have such file.

Comment: @vanowm Sorry, what do you imply by that? I don't fully understand that question

Comment: create a manifest.json https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/

Comment: Try adding a listener example: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'`

Comment: content document = a webpage
@Sega, background script don't have `document`, since it's not part of the DOM...

Comment: All the more reason to try with `window`

Comment: how would I use that? @Sega

Comment: @CassioTDS try this to see `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    window.document.getElementsByClassName('nav rbx-navbar hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4')
});` or simply `window.document.getElementsByClassName('nav rbx-navbar hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-5 col-lg-4')`. But I am not sure it that you are looking for.

Comment: @sega, so what you are saying, that `document` will magically become available if we wait long enough? background scripts don't have access to the `document`. That's why background scripts defined as .js file in manifest.json, and not as .html like options page or content script. There is no DOM for background scripts.

Comment: @vanow I understood well but it costs nothing by testing I think.

Comment: @Sega When doing so, I get a background error (Service worker registration failed), any more help?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You should do with :

```
document.querySelectorAll()
```

Example :

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("h1, div");
```

You can't use `.getElementByClassName()` because `getElementByClassName()` only applies to single elements.

Different from `querySelectorAll()` which is flexible to select all variants of elements.

You will always find undefined if you use `getElementsByClassName()` for your case.

Example `getElementsByClassName()`:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg" onclick="reddenPage()">Click me</button>
<div class="same"></div>
<div class="same"></div>
<div class="same"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function reddenPage(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('same');
    console.log(x[0]);
    if(x[0]==null){
        alert("element found "+x.length);
    }else{
        alert("element found "+x.length);
    }
}
```

Example `queryselectorAll()`:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg" onclick="reddenPage_()">Click me</button>
<div class="diffrent-1"></div>
<div class="diffrent-2"></div>
<div class="diffrent-3"></div>
<div class="diffrent-4"></div>
```

Javascript:
function reddenPage_(){
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.diffrent-1, .diffrent-2, .diffrent-3, .diffrent-4');
console.log(x[0]);
if(x[0]==null){
alert("element found "+x.length);
}else{
alert("element found "+x.length);
}
}

Example `getElementsByClassName()` will return `undefined`:

```
function reddenPage_(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('diffrent-1 diffrent-2 diffrent-3 diffrent-4');
    console.log(x[0]);
    if(x[0]==null){
        alert("element found "+x.length);
    }else{
        alert("element found "+x.length);
    }
}

//Response undefined
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? `document` is undefined.